# ([False, True] and [True, True]) evaluates to [True, True]

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I have observed the following behavior in python 3:

```
>>> ([False, True] and [True, True])
[True, True]

>>> ([False, True] or [True, True])
[False, True]
```

I was expecting exactly the opposite:

```
[False, True] and [True, True] = [False and True, True and True] = [False, True]
[False, True] or [True, True] = [False or True, True or True] = [True, True]
```

How does the observed behavior makes sense and how can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: *why* were you expecting `[False, True] and [True, True] = [False and True, True and True]` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is how it works in R and Fortran. They evaluate the vectors element-wise.

Comment: R and Fortran are usings arrays, and not plain old lists (hence why numpy fills the gap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use numpy. Standard lib python is evaluating:

```py
bool([False, True]) and bool([True, True])
```

Since both are True, it selects the last (try out `1 and 2`)

if you did:

```py
import numpy
numpy.bitwise_and([False, True], [True, True])
```

You'll get what you want.

If you don't want to use numpy, you need to write a list comprehension or loop:

```py
result = [(x and y) for x, y in zip([False, True], [True, True])]
```

Answer (score 5):

Each list is being evaluated as a whole.  `[False, True]` is True, and so is `[True, True]` because only an empty list is False.

`and` returns the last True element, but `or` returns the first one.

Comment: and how do I evaluate element-wise?

Comment: @rvbarreto you need to introduce a loop.  `zip` might be useful.

Comment: Neither of those lists is `True`. They're just true. Unclear what you mean with True.

Comment: @superbrain they both evaluate as `True` when used in a boolean context, because they're not empty.

Comment: I guess that might be correct, although as far as I know that'd be an implementation detail. The [documentation of `if`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) for example only talks about true, not about `True`.

Comment: @superbrain you're nitpicking.  There are two constants of `bool` type, `True` and `False`.  It's useful to speak in terms of those constants because they're the canonical representations of true and false in Python.  The expression `bool(x)` will return one or the other no matter what `x` is.

Comment: Hmm, in your answer you're not saying `True`, you're saying True. And if you *were* saying `True`, i.e., if you were saying "`[False, True]` is `True`", that would simply be wrong and misleading. I just don't understand why people can't just say true/false like Python's documentation consistently does, and make up words like truthy/falsy or (first time I've seen this) True/False.

Comment: @superbrain I'm saying `bool([False, True])` is `True`. And you're still nitpicking.  Drop it.

Comment: Not in your answer. You don't have `bool(...)` there.

Comment: @superbrain nitpicking again.  "Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated": https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: That's not even applicable here, since we don't have an operation or function here. Unless you mean the `and` and `or` from the question, which are operations, but they don't (in general) have a Boolean result. Which is even explicitly mentioned in the very next sentence after your quote. So I guess your point with that must be the "unless otherwise stated"? I don't see what sense that makes, though. That rather argues against yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Python does not provide element-wise operations on lists. You can use list comprehensions:

```
l1 = [False, True] 
l2 = [True, True]
[x and y for x,y in zip(l1, l2)]
#[False, True]
```

Note that the `np.bitwise_and` recommended elsewhere is about an order of magnitude *slower*.

Comment: The problem with this question is that `list(zip(l1, l2)) == list(l1, l2)`, so it's tough to know how to actually loop through everything

Comment: @PaulH I am not sure what you mean.  `list(l1, l2)` is illegal, in the first place.

Comment: sorry, i mean that `list(zip(l1, l2)) == [l1, l2]` for the example data provided. So it's hard to know which comparisons the OP is actually making.

Answer (score 0):

From [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Your expression `([False, True] and [True, True])` is an `x and y` expression, where your x is `[False, True]` and your y is `[True, True]`. Now is x false, or is it true? Also from that documentation:

> the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

So x is true, and thus the `and` operation returns y. Which is exactly what you got.

Likewise for `or`.

Another way to get the element-wise operations you want:

```
>>> x, y = [False, True], [True, True]
>>> from operator import and_, or_
>>> [*map(and_, x, y)]
[False, True]
>>> [*map(or_, x, y)]
[True, True]
```