# Where does the current documentation specify that [5] is true?

Tags: python

**Background:** I was going to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63514136/13008439), starting with something like "The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) specifies that non-empty lists are true and [...]". But then I realized that it doesn't specify that anymore. At least not obviously, which it used to.

Up to Python 3.5, the documentation [still said](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) (emphasis mine):

> 4.1. Truth Value Testing
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
> condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
> values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or `bool`
>   value `False`. [1]
>
> **All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.**
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return `0` or `False` for false and `1` or `True` for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations `or` and `and` always return one of their operands.)

A non-empty list like `[5]` doesn't fall under anything in the above list, so the "All other" specifies that it's true.

But since Python 3.6, that is gone. That section [now says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Truth Value Testing
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while`
> condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
> either a `__bool__()` method that returns `False` or a `__len__()` method
> that returns zero, when called with the object. [1] Here are most of the
> built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`.
> - zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
> - empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return `0` or `False` for false and `1` or `True` for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations `or` and `and` always return one of their operands.)

Now `[5]` could have a `__bool__()` method that returns `False`, and thus it would be false. Is there a new place in the current documentation that somehow specifies that non-empty lists are true?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220249/discussion-on-question-by-superb-rain-where-does-the-current-documentation-speci).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of all the built-in classes list all the special methods that they implement. If a method isn't listed, you can assume it isn't implemented.

Since the documentation of `list` doesn't say anything about overriding the `__bool__` method, it inherits the default behavior.

To find all the `list` operations, start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists). However, it also points out that lists implement all the [common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common) and [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) sequence operations, so you'll need to read that documentation for the complete list.

Comment: Could you give a link to the documentation of `list`'s special methods?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to the documentation.

Comment: I'll have a closer look tomorrow. At first sight, your "here" link only names the `sort` method, and the other two places talk about operations but not about methods. None of them mention the `__len__` method, for example. Even though `list.__len__` does exist.

Comment: The common sequence documentation mentions `len()`. `__len__` is the low-level method used to implement that.

Comment: Maybe that's an argument. I'll think about it tomorrow. But at this point we're faaaaar away from something obvious that I could just point to. Have a look at the first paragraph I added to my question, about the background.

Comment: I think you just have wrong expectations. The default is just what you intuitively expect it to be.

Comment: Well I can't just tell somehow to use their intuition when they've already demonstrated that their intuition is wrong, can I?

Comment: I'm running out of arguments.

Comment: The basic idea is that nothing "unusual" happens without being documented. Having a non-default boolean mapping is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a place, [in the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) (emphasis mine):

> 6.11. Boolean operations
>
> [...]
>
> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are
> used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted
> as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings
> and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets
> and frozensets). **All other values are interpreted as true.**
> User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a
> `__bool__()` method.

It bothers me a little that that's right away contradicted by the very next sentence, about user-defined objects, but I'll take it.

Answer (score -1):

`[5]` is a `list` object.  Unless  you have specifically overridden the built-in `__bool__` method, you get the default method.  As the documentation already implied, this is *Truthy*.

The update doesn't change things so much as widen the explanation to cover derived types and other augmentations of the built-in types.

Comment: I get the default method? I just tested it, `list.__bool__` doesn't exist. I'd say if *you* don't know that, then the average reader of the documentation also doesn't know that. Hence there's something missing.

Comment: Good shot: the `__bool__` method is inherited from a parent class.  However, that doesn't nullify your point: the average reader wouldn't know.  However, I feel that the average reader would take the intended meaning of the documentation: by default, the example semantics are what you get.  If you think that `[5]` should be Falsey, then you need to take specific action to make it so.

Comment: Hmm, `[5].__bool__` also doesn't exist. Shouldn't it if that's inherited? Or what do you mean with that?

Comment: You're going to make a good, investigative programmer (or maybe you already are one)!  `[5]` is a constant in a built-in type; the notation doesn't work the same way.  This just isn't the time or place to digress ... and I'd love to see you post your digging attempts as a separate question!

Comment: Sorry to keep "digressing", but what do you mean the notation doesn't work the same way? How do I see that inherited `__bool__` method?